# jQuery strange behaviour on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the site

http://offline.raileisure.com/

the 2 custom radio buttons 'Station MAsters House' and 'Carriage' doesn't seem to run the function of jquery when changed.

its something to do with the custom class 'styled'

there should be a simple alert when changed but it doesn't work.... it does work however if i take out the class='styled'

Thanks

Lee

Comment: please provide the html/js code

Comment: If you could add some source code, we can help better. How did you bind the change functions ?

Comment: Found the site, by looking at his previous questions. Lee: Next time do not assume we know what you asked previously

Comment: The radio buttons seem to work. I don't know what "run the function of jQuery" means, and I doubt anybody else does either :-)

Comment: Looking at the site my guess is your javascript responds to the click on the input. However, your styling replaces the input with a span. I think you're looking at the wrong element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "Style" it, it is no longer an active radio button

```
<td style="line-height:2em;">
<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0pt -48px;"></span>
<input class="styled" type="radio" value="2" name="property">
Carriage
</td>
```

It has display=none and is not what you are clicking
This works

```
$(".radio").click(function() {
  $(this).next('input').attr("checked","checked");
});
```

### [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/XpdkQ/)

Comment: @Lee Now it does. closest() is UP the tree, next() is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;` line in `custom-elements.js` is the trouble maker.

One shot in the blue... can you try

```
$("input[name='property']").live("change", function(e) {
    alert("change");
});
```